# Using javascript variables anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my jQuery function,

```
$.post("assets/scripts/chat/get_user_info.php", {UserID: UserID}, function(data){
if (data == "error") {
alertBar('negative','There was an error sending the message');
}
var username = data;
})
```

But I only use the "data" or "username" variable in the function itself, so how can I use it globally around the whole page?

Comment: create global variable username and assign the data in function.

Comment: Whatever answer you pick, do not forget to declare variables. It's perfectly legal to set a *property* in the global scope using `window.username = data;`. However, not declaring a variable using `var` is a bad practice, and will throw errors in strict mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define variable in the global scope, outside your function.

`var username, data;`

`$.post("assets/scripts . . .`

Answer (score 2):

Either

`window.data = data`

or

`username = data`

The thing is though,the `$.post` is asynchronous, so you won't be able to do something like...

```
$.post( ... )
alert(window.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var globalData;
var username;

$.post("assets/scripts/chat/get_user_info.php", {UserID: UserID}, function(data){
    if (data == "error") {
        alertBar('negative','There was an error sending the message');
    }
    globalData = data
    username = data;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is

```
  var myglobaldata = {};

$.post("assets/scripts/chat/get_user_info.php", {UserID: UserID}, function(data){
if (data == "error") {
alertBar('negative','There was an error sending the message');
}
  myglobaldata.username = data;
})
```

Now you can access `myglobaldata.username` from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could save it as data using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$.post("assets/scripts/chat/get_user_info.php", {UserID: UserID}, function(data){
    if (data == "error") {
        alertBar('negative','There was an error sending the message');
    } else {
        $(document).data('userInfo', data);
    }
});
```

Then you can access it by doing:

```
var userInfo = $(document).data('userInfo');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.username = data
```

Will make it a global variable. Though this is often considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.username` instead of `username`

`document` object is visible from everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I assume your jQuery is wrapped in `$(document).ready();` - try declaring the vars outside like this, which will make them global throughout the page:

```
var username, data;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("assets/scripts/chat/get_user_info.php", {UserID: UserID}, function(data){
    if (data == "error") {
        alertBar('negative','There was an error sending the message');
    }
    username = data;
    })
});
```

Comment: The whole thing is inside a function.